# Rails controller not loading extended class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on, pg-search

I am using rails (5.0.7.2) for a small project. For tags I choose the acts-as-taggable-on and for search pg_search gems. As I want the tags to be searchable, I first created a folder in the app directory called "utilities". Then I crated a file called "search_tags.rb" in that folder.

The content:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do
  # includes
  include PgSearch

  # search scope
  pg_search_scope :search, against: {
    name: 'A',
  },
  using: {
    tsearch: {
      dictionary: 'english',
      prefix: true
    }
  }

  class SearchTags; end

end
```

However if I want to use that search function on the tags in my tags controller I get a "method undefined" error. If I include the code from the file above right
in the controller action it works properly. Thus I guess it may be not loaded at all
from that new folder.

What would be the proper way of making the content from the extension available to 
my controller?

Update:

I created:

```
# app/models/concerns/searchable.rb
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include PgSearch

    # search scope
    pg_search_scope :search, against: {
      name: 'A',
    },
    using: {
      tsearch: {
        dictionary: 'english',
        prefix: true
      } 
    }
  end
end
```

I removed utilities folder and the file. In the tags controller now I do

```
class ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
  include Searchable
end
```

This works and looks a bit better. However not optimal. At least it does not feel to good to have the class call and that include in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better approach might be to move this into a concern and include the concern in your model (concerns should get autoloaded by default). Something like this might work.

```rb
# app/models/concerns/searchable.rb
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include PgSearch

    # search scope
    pg_search_scope :search, against: {
      name: 'A',
    },
    using: {
      tsearch: {
        dictionary: 'english',
        prefix: true
      } 
    }
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/act_as_taggable_on/tag.rb
class ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
  include Searchable
end
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is really working. The model of ActsAsTaggableOn is in the gem itself and not in my project folder. Thus the trick with model evaluation to open up the class and add a funciton. I cannot simply include somthing there, but maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: You can create the `app/models/act_as_taggable_on/tag.rb` file and it should reopen it or you do your trick with the `class_eval` and include the concern.

Comment: Nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default everything in `app/` is autoloaded, but in `config/application.rb` you could add:

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/utilities/)`

to include utilities as well. Or you could do it in `config/environments/...` to do it on a per environment basis

Comment: You are right. Everything in app/ is autoloaded. Even without having to specify the folder explicitly (as you suggest). I find the new folder added to the autoload paths. But the function from the file in that folder seems not to be run or imported.